# How to replace string within parenthesis using using sed

Tags: text-processing

I have the following string:

```
col1|col2|col3+++++++++++A|1|a B|2|b C|3|c D|4|d  (3 rows)
```

I want to split this string so as to remove the string in the beginning till the last + symbol and then remove the tail end which is (XYZ rows)

so the string becomes `A|1|a B|2|b C|3|c D|4|d`
Now, I want to split this string into multiple arrays that look like this

```
A 1 a 
B 2 b 
C 3 c 
D 4 d
```

so that I can iterate over each row using for loop to do some processing.

How can I do this using sed or grep?

I tried this for the first pass but it didn't work

```
echo $string | sed 's/([0-9])rows//' | sed 's/[^+]//'
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By variable expansion in bash:

```
str="col1|col2|col3+++++++++++A|1|a B|2|b C|3|c D|4|d  (3 rows)"
str=${str%  (*}
str=${str##*+}
str=${str// /
}
str=${str//|/ }
```

Or by **sed**

```
sed 's/.*+\(.*\S\)\s\+(.*/\1/;y/ |/\n /' <<\eof
col1|col2|col3+++++++++++A|1|a B|2|b C|3|c D|4|d  (3 rows)
eof
A 1 a
B 2 b
C 3 c
D 4 d
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "col1|col2|col3+++++++++++A|1|a B|2|b C|3|c D|4|d  (3 rows)" |sed -e 's/.*\++//; s/d .*/d/; s/|\(.\)|\(.\)\s*/ \1 \2\n/g'

A 1 a
B 2 b
C 3 c
D 4 d
```